# Angular - Load image from wwwroot / upload

Tags: angular, image, upload, http-status-code-404, wwwroot

I created an application where you can upload the image and it's looking good, but I meet a problem when I want to load this file on the form.

For example I have config in C#:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")));
```

and later:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
```

and for example I have folder:

```
wwwroot -> upload -> 1162491080637832185565989557.jpg
```

I'm trying load this file in this way:

```
<img src="upload/1855610264637832204162556760.jpg" alt="">
```

but I still got 404. I don't know why because this file exists on the drive.

Best Regards,
Krzysztof.

Comment: What is the actual path the browser requests the image on? Maybe add a / in front of upload helps?

Comment: the real link is looking like that: "https://localhost:44468/upload/1855610264637832204162556760.jpg" I tried adding / at first but still was not working.

Comment: And you angular app is running there as well I assume? Same URL?

Comment: Yes exactly. I think I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved my problem in a clean way.
Just added configuration to the Proxy file and everything is working fine.